# django - annotation based on field calculations

Tags: django, annotations

Is it possible to annotate objects with calculations (which are not the trivial sum\max\min\count) based on other fields?

Examples:

- To add a time annotation field based on an existing TimeField field with addition of a certain time interval
- To add an integer annotation that is a certain calculation based on two IntegerFields fields

A workaround for at least some of the cases (e.g. the first of the two examples) would be having an `update()` command that does not save. That would allow me to change a certain field in a QuerySet, and use it locally without changing the entries in the db. Alas, AFAIK `update()` always saves.

A solution would be of course to list the queryset and add a field using list comprehension, but I was hoping for a more djangoic way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this sort of thing (if I’m understanding it correctly) using a [RawSQL annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#raw-sql-expressions):

```
queryset = City.objects.annotate(distance=
        RawSQL('sqrt(((%s - latitude)/0.010)^2 + ((%s - longitude)/0.015)^2)',
               (latitude, longitude))) \
    .filter(distance__lte=radius) \
    .order_by('distance')
```

It annotates the cities with something akin to their distances to a point (straight through the earth and with other wacky assumptions, but that’s not relevant to this question).

You can often just implement a property on your model class in cases where you don’t need the annotation (here `distance`) for filtering in the same query.